# How to read queries of master that sends to slaves?

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to see queries that Master sends to slaves in Mysql ?
Is there a way to see that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SEE QUERIES AS THEY HAPPEN ON THE SLAVE

On a running Slave, you should see to connections with the username `system user`

Login to the Slave and run this

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user WHERE user = 'system user'\G
```

## SEE QUERIES BEFORE THE SLAVE GETS TO PROCESS THEM

On a running Master, the binary logs contains all completed SQL commands.

To the see the commands, you need to use the [**mysqlbinlog command utility**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqlbinlog.html) agaunst the binary logs on the Master or you could run it against the relay logs on the Slave

Here are my earlier posts on how to apply mysqlbinlog in a variety of ways

- `Feb 18, 2014` : [mysqlbinlog failing with " ERROR 1032 (HY000) at line 48: Can't find record in `` " Error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59101/mysqlbinlog-failing-with-error-1032-hy000-at-line-48-cant-find-record-in/59103#59103)
- `Sep 06, 2013` : [MySQL : Extract SQL statements from binlog](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49409/mysql-extract-sql-statements-from-binlog/49411#49411)
- `Sep 03, 2013` : [Get missed transactions from slave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48886/get-missed-transactions-from-slave/49190#49190)
- `Feb 04, 2013` : [MySQL Point in Time Recovery For Just a Single Schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34086/mysql-point-in-time-recovery-for-just-a-single-schema/34088#34088)
- `Aug 16, 2012` : [How to see what was executed in the database via binlogs for specific date?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22611/how-to-see-what-was-executed-in-the-database-via-binlogs-for-specific-date/22646#22646)
- `May 26, 2012` : [Trying to understand SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/trying-to-understand-show-slave-status-g/18438#18438)
- `Oct 26, 2011` : [Multi-threaded replay of master activity for load/performance testing](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6391/multi-threaded-replay-of-master-activity-for-load-performance-testing/7280#7280)